# JUnit test MongoDB SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I am trying do test in my app SpringBoot with MongoDB embebed but I have a error when I run my app, It's my first time, I never do test with Springboot, mongodb,junit...

First I add in my pom.xml this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

With this dependency I will have mongoDB embebed ( But I don't know if this version is correct...)

Then I created two class java:

1º

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class))
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    GenerarCsv service() {
        return new GenerarCsvImpl();
    }
}
```

In this class I have my interface and I will generate my implementation, now my 2º class java:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.batch.DesarrolloBatch.model.Documento;
import com.batch.DesarrolloBatch.persistence.DocumentoRepository;
import com.batch.DesarrolloBatch.service.interfaces.GenerarCsv;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.IMongodConfig;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.Net;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Version;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Network;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class GenerarDocumentoTest {

    @Autowired
    private GenerarCsv service; 

    @Autowired
    private DocumentoRepository repository;


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "documento";

    private MongodExecutable mongodExe;
    private MongodProcess mongod;
    private MongoClient mongo;

    @Before
    public void beforeEach() throws Exception {
        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        String bindIp = "localhost";
        int port = 27017;
        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
        .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
        .net(new Net(bindIp, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
        .build();
        this.mongodExe = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        this.mongod = mongodExe.start();
        this.mongo = new MongoClient(bindIp, port);
    }

    @After
    public void afterEach() throws Exception {
        if (this.mongod != null) {
            this.mongod.stop();
            this.mongodExe.stop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateNewObjectInEmbeddedMongoDb() {
        // given
        MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        db.createCollection("documento");
        MongoCollection<Documento> col = db.getCollection("documento", Documento.class);

        // when
        Documento doc = new Documento();
        doc.set_id("999999999999999999999999");
        col.insertOne(doc);

        // then
        assertEquals(1L, col.countDocuments());
    }

}
```

Ok, in this class I created the conexión with my mongoDB in memory, then I try insert a object type documento in mongDB, finally I ask if in my mongoDB I have 1 registred, however , I get error when I try run this application ->

```
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception; nested exception is de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:68) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.embeddedMongoServer(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67c9dfd6.CGLIB$embeddedMongoServer$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67c9dfd6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d580d09.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67c9dfd6.embeddedMongoServer(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.Downloader.downloadInputStream(Downloader.java:131) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.Downloader.download(Downloader.java:69) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ArtifactStore.checkDistribution(ArtifactStore.java:66) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedArtifactStore.checkDistribution(ExtractedArtifactStore.java:60) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:55) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-1.50.1.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
```

If I copy these link "htpp..... .zip" in my navigated, I CAN download these .zip, then I don't know why SpringBoot doesn't can download the .zip.

Finally, I want renember that I don't know do this, I was copy and paste the others post in google. If anyone know how do Junit test with mongoDB in Springboot is my objective final. It's my first time. Thanks.

EDIT:

I change my dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now when I run my app, she is download, but always is 0% never up...

```
019-06-12 09:45:02.242  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.b.D.GenerarDocumentoTest               : The following profiles are active: test
2019-06-12 09:45:03.108  INFO 14372 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-06-12 09:45:03.282  INFO 14372 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 166ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-06-12 09:45:04.005  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.e.EmbeddedMongo                : Download Version{3.5.5}:Windows:B64 : starting...
2019-06-12 09:45:06.621  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.e.EmbeddedMongo                : Download Version{3.5.5}:Windows:B64 : DownloadSize: 245893992
2019-06-12 09:45:08.809  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.e.EmbeddedMongo                : Download Version{3.5.5}:Windows:B64 : 0 %
```

Comment: As per the exception, it is clear that it is trying to download MongoDB and SocketTimeoutException is getting thrown. I presume maybe it was just temporary network glitch causing to download from the internet. Give it a try once more!!

Comment: you can customize your download url using this: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#customize-download-url. You can download manually this file and place it in one of your reachable web-servers to download it.

Comment: I am trying this since yesterday .....

Comment: Another possibility is your firewall is blocking the download access of your java runtime. Check if temporarily disable firewall will fix the issue. Or as Sunil suggest above, download the jar manually first.

Comment: I edit my post, in other part, I don't know download the git and implements these... thanks

Comment: Do you run it under a proxy ?

Answer (score 4):

Method de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.LocalArtifactStore.getArtifact(IDownloadConfig runtime, Distribution distribution) checks the user's local folder to see if the distribution file already exists locally. This method will return null if it does not already exist.

The calling method will then try to download the file, timeout, and throw a de.flapdoodle.embed.process.distribution.Distributon.DistributionException wrapping the IO exception.

This interrupts spring boot runtime injection and all tests depending on this fail.

Download the file http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip

On windows, copy it to your user folder like this:
c:\users\your_user_name\.embeddedmongo\win32\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.5.5.zip

Now run your tests and it will extract the embedded server executable to 
c:\users\your_user_name\.embeddedmongo\extracted\Windows-B64--3.5.5\extractmongod.exe

Your tests should now run properly.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue, is there any reason why the download fails?

Comment: This location didnt help me any idea?